# No module named 'tokenize'

Tags: anaconda, conda

Trouble with anaconda: 
  Error message below. 
     Reason why I think this is happening:
    Accidentally deleted some files

I tried to uninstall Anaconda, and reinstall, however, when reinstalling - installer says Anaconda already installed, hence, not able to get Anaconda working.

Scanned through the net and stackoverflow, but unable to find an answer. Error message below:

```
"
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/miniconda3/bin/conda", line 13, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 149, in main
        from ..exceptions import conda_exception_handler
      File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 10, in <module>
        from logging import getLogger
      File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
        import sys, os, time, io, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections.abc
      File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
        import linecache
      File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
        import tokenize
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tokenize' "
```

Comment: Have you followed all the instructions at http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/ ?

Comment: Hi @nekomatic thanks for ypur answer, problem resolved alr